# How to show loading spinner / indicator when InAppBrowser launches for iOS version of Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

We are trying to display an indicator that the web page is loading when launching an instance of InAppBrowser on iOS version of Cordova 3.4.

Android works fine with a spinner on the bottom, but iOS shows nothing but a white screen until the page suddenly pops up.

We were initially looking into using event listeners:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/dev/doc/index.md#addeventlistener

to listen to loadstart and loadstop and add js/css to show loading within the appbrowser window

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/dev/doc/index.md#executescript
and
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/dev/doc/index.md#insertcss

Still working on a viable solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The iOS InAppBrowser object has its own spinner which it adds to the webview automatically.

However, as the spinner is created as UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite and the background of the webview is white you can't see it.

So I updated this like so:

```
self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

Also, the x co-ordinate of the spinner's frame are outside the bounds of an iPhones view.  To fix this I updated the frame to:

```
self.spinner.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 10, self.view.frame.size.height/ 2 - 10, 20, 20);
```

This should centre the spinner no matter what size of device you are using.

I have only tested this in portrait mode.

You may want to fork Cordova (I'm testing this with 3.4) and submit a patch or see if there is a "proper" way to do this.

Comment: Very, very awesome
Do submit a pull request to the Cordova People pronto
This saves my day, temper, week and month :)

Comment: Forgot: It works in portrait in every resolution testable in the IOS simulator as well as available physical devices. Good work!

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but could you please update us who are not familiar with where to actually make these changes? I'm using Ionic, and am presuming you changed this in the Xcode, but could you please elaborate?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Ionic but this is in the iOS Cordova plugin InAppBrowser. If you are using Cordova then you need to update the code there if it has not already been fixed? You do this in XCode so if you are using this and Cordova then go into the Cordova project in your app and find this file and make this change.

Comment: I've created a fork and and pull request with my fix. We'll wait and see if it is used.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else using Phonegap Build, you can use my public plugin that implements these changes and makes the loading indicator (spinner) appear as it should in iOS.

Add this to your config.xml in your Phonegap Build project in place of the default InAppBrowser plugin to get the grey spinner described above by Goku:

`<gap:plugin name="com.cordova.plugin.inappbrowser.with.loading.spinner" version="1.0.2" />`

Comment: I had to make some small changes to make the spinner stay centered in portrait and landscape (previously was centered only in portrait view).

So, use the latest version to make sure that the spinner is centered in both orientations.The code is provided below (add to config.xml).

`<gap:plugin name="com.cordova.plugin.inappbrowser.with.loading.spinner" version="1.0.13" />`